# WCF websocket connection close on Windows8

Tags: wcf, websocket

I have a WebSocket WCF based server.
a web (HTML) client is connecting this server using WebSockets.

The server worked well with all clients, till we stumble a client, Chrome (And Firefox) running on Windows 8.1, that fails to connect.

The server receives "Open" request but in Wireshark we see that the connection is closed with unknown reason (21584).
the client shows no message/exception.

From time to time, long time after the failure, the server prints to the log and exception:
The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request

What can a reason for such problem? how can we overcome it? or what will be the best way to trace/debug this problem?

thanks.
R.